# About a pointer to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

Can anyone tell me about the differences of these:

1. `target_addr.sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *)(target->h_addr_list[0]);`
   This works well.
2. `target_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = (unsigned int)(*(target->h_addr));`
   `//h_addr = h_addr_list[0]`
   This line does not have any syntax error, but I do not know whether it works.
3. `target_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(struct in_addr *)(target->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;`
   Why does this line not work? I think the meaning of this line is exactly the same as the two above...

The variables come from:

```
struct hostent *target; 
struct sockaddr_in target_addr;
```

Comment: struct hostent *target;
struct sockaddr_in target_addr;

Comment: Shouldn't `h_addr` be defined as a macro with `#define`?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is defined in the header file netdb.h. And I included that.

Comment: Then why did you show it as a variable assignment in the question, instead of `#define`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely familiar with these structures, but I can comment on the pointers. Be careful of all the casting - are you **really** sure `h_addr` is storing what you think it is?

In your third line of code, `s_addr` isn't a pointer, and you're attempting to dereference it as if it were. Your three lines of code don't have the same meaning.

1. Here, you are **casting** `target->h_addr_list[0]` to a `pointer` to 
   `struct in_addr`. After that cast you are now operating on a `pointer` 
   to `struct in_addr`. You then **dereference** that `pointer`, loading
   the value into `sin_addr`.
2. Here, you are **dereferencing** `target->h_addr` ( which as someone
   mentioned is an alias of `target->h_addr_list[0]`) and then
   casting it to an unsigned int.
3. Here you are **casting** `target->h_addr_list[0]` to a `pointer` to
   `struct in_addr`, so far, same as #1. Then, you access the field
   `s_addr` of `struct in_addr`. The result of this access is the
   value of `struct in_addr.s_addr`.
   You then attempt to **dereference** that value, but it's not a
   `pointer`. I assume you're getting an **indirection related error** ?

Comment: Thank you. And I forget to mention this: #define h_addr h_addr_list[0] /* address, for backward compatibility */ in the header file netdb.h

Comment: h_addr_list is defined like this: char **h_addr_list;

Comment: But when I change "->" to ".", it still does not work

Comment: It's not the "->" in this statement that is dereferencing s_addr, it's the "*". You're dereferencing the pointer to struct in_addr with "->".

Comment: You mean I should delete "*"?

Comment: If I delete "*", then it is a pointer to a struct. Then I think it is right in syntax. But this still does not pass compiling thing

Comment: Oh, you need to encapsulate your cast, my mistake. Try this:  ((struct in_addr *)target->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr.

Comment: It seems that "->" will get working first, then the casting. Thank you for the encapsulate!

Comment: Then I found (*(struct in_addr *)(target->h_addr_list[0])).s_addr is also working in this situation